# scatter plot for each category separately not in the same graph in r

Tags: r, ggplot2, scatter-plot

I need help in creating a scatter plot for each category separately in the same graph for a variable with different colors as shown in the following picture. (Hb is continous variable and NO2 is catagorical variable (quintiles))

[image]

Comment: https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/facet_wrap.html.   What have you tried?

Comment: @jon spring, many thanks for your prompt reply. i new to r so don't know much

Comment: No problem. There are many tutorials for using facets in ggplot2. https://r4ds.hadley.nz/layers.html#facets.  Try some things out and if you run into specific obstacles this will be a helpful forum to overcome those.

Comment: @Jon Spring. thanks. i'll have a look and try. enjoy your rest of evening

Answer (score 0):

We'll need to see a minimum amount of example data to help. Here is one way to approach this type of chart:

```
library(tidyverse)
iris2<-iris %>% mutate(S2=paste(Species, 1:2, sep="-"))
iris2 %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=Sepal.Width, y=Sepal.Length, color=Petal.Length)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_wrap(vars(S2), nrow=3)
```

[image]